# Working with Unicode in VBA StrConv

Tags: vba, excel, unicode, utf-8

I have an Excel file and a userform where user can type in students' details and the form will check for duplication and then add the info onto the last line of a table. I want to improve it further by making the form capitalize the first letter of each name using this code:

```
Me.Surname.Value = StrConv(Me.Surname.Value, vbProperCase)
```

Me.Surname.Value is the input of the form, mostly Vietnamese such as Trần, Nguyễn, Thảo, etc. However, they are changed into something like Tr?n, Nguy?n, Th?o after going through StrConv. I read some suggestions and change my locale to Vietnamese but the problem persists.

Do you have any suggestion to fix this? I am thinking of converting the inputs into hex value and then write them down using ChrW(), but I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: You would need to use StrConv() to convert the string from whatever encoding it uses, or include a locale maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a bit with this and the culprit seems to be `StrConv`.
It works for me if instead of using `StrConv` I explicitely set the proper case:

```
Surname.Text = UCase(Left(Surname.Text, 1)) & Mid(Surname.Text, 2)
```

or even more precise:

```
Surname.Text = UCase(Left(Surname.Text, 1)) & Mid(LCase(Surname.Text), 2)
```

Comment: Thank you. It really seems like `StrConv` is what went wrong. I am new to VBA, so I didn't know about `UCase` and `LCase`. With this, I can make everything work now.